Efficiently Embedding Long Text Input for OpenAI API in Node.js
I'm developing an API in Node.js that utilizes the OpenAI API to summarize long responses. However, I'm encountering issues with token size and cost optimization due to the length of the text input. I've heard about embedding the input text into a vector to mitigate these issues, but I'm struggling to find a suitable solution in JavaScript.
Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to efficiently embed long text inputs for the OpenAI API in Node.js? Any insights on best practices or libraries that can help with this task would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried implementing using llama,
I am expecting like, How can I provide long response to ChatGpt open, AI, whithout exceeding token size
